# Send a text email attachment with Emoji

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mime-types, email-attachments

My app is sending email with a .txt file attachment (the file is built in the documents directory, and is essentially a log file). The file has emoji characters embedded throughout the text

I use the following code to produce an email with this .txt file as an attachment. The code works fine and emails arrive as expected, except I don't know which mime type to use to preserve the emoji. So, when the .txt file arrives, the emoji are flattened.

Which mime type should I use?

```
    NSData *textData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:debugLogPath];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailer setMessageBody:@"Some body" isHTML:YES];
    [mailer setSubject:@"some subject"];

    NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a---@b---.com", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:recipients];

    [mailer addAttachmentData:textData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:destinationFileName];
```

**Edit**: added line reading the data from the .txt file

Comment: Well mime type should be `text/plain`. text/plain usage UTF-8 encoding which is fine for emoticons (or emojis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the code posted above works just fine. There apparently was some garage in the log file on **some** users' machines that caused emoji to appear as an escape sequence, while other machines were observed to work as expected. After publishing an update to all users that wiped and restarted the log file, the emoji appear properly intact in the email attachment for all users.